# Help with simple SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I have a user table and user_friend table. user_friend shows who I am friend with (so it's uid and fid). I want to get the info of all my friends, so I did:

```
SELECT UID, Name FROM user WHERE UID = (SELECT FID FROM user_friend WHERE UID = 567445724);
```

but it gives me a Subquery returns more than 1 row, how should I modify this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try JOIN like

```
select u.uid,u.name 
   from user u join user_freinds uf on u.uid=uf.fid 
        where u.uid=567445724
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT UID, Name FROM user
WHERE UID IN (SELECT FID FROM user_friend WHERE UID = 567445724);`
```

Alternatively, in MySQL, I believe I recall reading that joins are often much fasdter than subselects. So perhaps:

`SELECT user.UID, user.Name FROM user, user_friend
WHERE user.UID = user_friend.FID AND user_friend.UID =  567445724;`

Comment: wonder why this only returns one entries while actually the subquery returns 2... and yes the fid is in the uid

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `in` keyword.

```
SELECT UID, Name FROM user WHERE UID IN (SELECT FID FROM user_friend WHERE UID = 567445724);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IN instead of equals:

```
SELECT UID, Name FROM user WHERE UID IN (SELECT FID FROM user_friend WHERE UID = 567445724);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select user.uid, user.name from user, user_friends 
where user.uid=user_friends.fid 
  and user.uid=567445724
```